# PHP: undefined offset while importing from csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I guess you don't have to look at the entire code, but I'll include it anyway.

```
<?php if (!$_POST) { ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div class="header">
  <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />

</div>

<body background="images/background.png" >

        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Choose your file: <br /> 
            <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> <br /> <br /> 
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
} else {
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "csvdb");
if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) {
    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $i = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($i > 0) {
$import = "INSERT into csvtb(project_id,unit_id,phase,building,level,orientation,apartment_type,size,garden,garden_and_terrace_size,bedrooms,parking,floorplan,sold) values('$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]''$data[11]','$data[12]','$data[13],'$data[14])";
            $connect->query($import);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    print "Import done";
}
}
?>
```

the error is on line 30, undefined offset

```
$import = "INSERT into csvtb(project_id,unit_id,phase,building,level,orientation,apartment_type,size,garden,garden_and_terrace_size,bedrooms,parking,floorplan,sold) values('$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]''$data[11]','$data[12]','$data[13],'$data[14])";
            $connect->query($import);
```

I checked my code using many php online checking tools, they say the code is clean. I guess I know what's the error, i guess it's because I'm not inserting into index 0, that's because I want that to be the id for my database. I'm not sure though, if I were I wouldn't have asked. My PHP skills aren't that good I guess.

Comment: Your SQL is flat-out wrong. Youve multiple mismatched/dangling `'` in there. and if you get undefined offset, you're trying to access an index in the array that doesn't exist. do `var_dump($data)` to see what the csv data looks like at that point. you'll probably find it's short by 1 or more fields compared to the other lines.

Comment: You are starting at index 1, I think you need to start with index 0. `$data[0]` instead of `$data[1]` in your `INSERT` query.

Comment: @RST that's what I thought too and mentioned in my question

Comment: well did you change it to check it?

Comment: @RST yes i just did, didnt solve it

Comment: Did you renumber all the `$data[]` indexes or just the first one? The point is, there is probably no `$data[14]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some lines in your CSV has less data than supplied to the query. I'd recommend handling that in a manner that you can log/debug.

Using your sample code, I have just done some early-exits if data is not found to be valid. You could apply the same kind of logic and print out the lines that do not have total of 15 array element. It appears you are skipping element 0 and choosing 1..14. That's absolutely fine; just check to ensure that all lines are giving you 15 array elements.

```
<?php 
if ($_POST) 
{
    $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "csvdb");
    if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) 
    {
        //get the csv file 
        $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");

        $i = 0;
        $expected_array_count = 15;

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            // skip first line
            if ($i == 0) { i++; continue; }

            // print offending line and continue to the next line 
            // if array does not have the expected count
            if (count(data) !== $expected_array_count) 
            {
                echo sprintf("Line %d has %d lines; %d expected: %s",
                    $i+1,
                    count(data),
                    $expected_array_count,
                    implode("~~", $array)
                );

                i++;
                continue;
            }

            performImport($data);
            $i++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
        print "Import done";
    }
<?php
}

else 
{
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <div class="header">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    </div>

    <body background="images/background.png" >
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Choose your file: <br /> 
                <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> <br /> <br /> 
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
}


// function does the importing
function performImport($data)
{
    global $connect;

    // instead of entering data like this, there are 
    // better alternatives
    $import = "
    INSERT into csvtb
    (
        project_id,unit_id,phase,
        building,level,orientation,
        apartment_type,size,garden,
        garden_and_terrace_size,bedrooms,parking,
        floorplan,sold
    ) 
    values
    (
        '$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]',
        '$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]',
        '$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]',
        '$data[10]','$data[11]','$data[12]',
        '$data[13]','$data[14]'
    )";

    // one alterate
    // $import = sprintf("insert into ... values (%d, %s, %d...)", $data[1], $data[2] ...)

    // another alternate (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
    // $import = "insert into ... values (?, ?, ...)"
    // mysqli_stmt_bind_param($import, 'sss...', $data[1], $data[2]...);

    // yet another alternate: use PDO
    $connect->query($import);
}
?>
```